# Why am I getting an error messaging when trying to set default value of public method a color?

Tags: c#, properties

I have something like this:

```
[Description("Sets the color."),
Category("Values"),
DefaultValue(Color.White),
Browsable(true)]
public Color MyColor
{
    get
    {
        return myColor;
    }
    set
    {
        myColor = value;
    }
}
private Color myColor = Color.White;
```

I'm getting an error at this line:

```
DefaultValue(Color.White),
```

If the value is a boolean there isn't a problem, but when trying to set it to a color I get:
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Can anyone identify the problem?

Comment: Would there be a way to set the color utilizing the DefaultValue field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Color.White` isn't a constant expression; it rather is a <strike>`readonly` field</strike> `static property`<sup>1</sup> and involves instantiation.

**Edit**:

For your information, an alternative way to set a `Color`'s default value might look like this:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "White"]
public Color MyColor
{ ... }
```

<sub>1. [Ed Swangren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053/ed-swangren) pointed this out in his answer</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Because the predefined color objects in the Color struct are not constants, they are static properties with only a get accessor.

```
public static Color Transparent { get; }
```

That line actually return a new Color object by using the values in the KnownColor enum to construct it:

```
public static Color Transparent 
{ 
    get { return new Color( KnownColor.Transparent ); } 
}
```

So, as you can see, there is nothing constant about calling that method, which is why you receive an error.

Answer (score 0):

The error description says it all :)
Try to put there the color value as string (mean 'constant expression').

PS. in your code there is a default value set to the private member, so you can skip this attribute.